# Proving that this sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two polynomial functions, and $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of complex numbers.
$$\forall z \in \mathbb C, |P(z)| \geq Q(|z|)$$
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} |P(z_n)| = m = \inf(\{|P(z)|: z\in\mathbb C\})$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow +\infty} Q(x) = +\infty$$
Is this information enough to prove that $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is bounded?

### I tried:

Finding a contradiction if $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ were to be unbounded. My idea was to show that $(|P(z_n)|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would diverge but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Since $Q$ is a polynomial for which

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} Q(x) = \infty$$

it is true that

$$\lim_{z \to \infty} |Q(z)| = \infty$$
(meaning, in all directions). This is because the degree of $Q$ must be at least $1$, and all non-constant polynomials have a pole at infinity. Hence $P$ also has a pole at infinity, and then by continuity attains its minimum at some point in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the goal here is to prove that it attains ils minimun, so I'd prefer not to use that as an argument ;)

Comment: @Ghuizing It follows from continuity: Since $P$ blows up at infinity, there's a ball off of which $|P(z)|$ is greater than some number you choose (e.g. $2 |P(0)|$). Now that ball is compact, and by the usual work, $|P|$ attains a minimum within that ball.